# Spring application can't reach jsp pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my spring application, I using the configuration based on java code instead xml files. When I try access any page from my application, the browser is redirect to the correct mapped url, but I still face a 404 error page.

My controller class is created this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="acesso")
public class AcessoController {

    @RequestMapping(value="login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("acesso/login");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

My WebAppInitializer.java is this:

```
@Order(value=1)
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext jspContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      jspContext.register(JspDispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic jsp_dispatcher = container.addServlet("jsp_dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(jspContext));
      jsp_dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      jsp_dispatcher.addMapping("*.jsp");

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext jsonContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      jsonContext.register(JsonDispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic json_dispatcher = container.addServlet("json_dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(jsonContext));
      json_dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(2);
      json_dispatcher.addMapping("*.json");

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext xmlContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      xmlContext.register(XmlDispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic xml_dispatcher = container.addServlet("xml_dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(jspContext));
      xml_dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(3);
      xml_dispatcher.addMapping("*.xml");
    }

}
```

My jspDispatcherConfig.java is this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(WebAppConfig.class)
public class JspDispatcherConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

In my folder WEB-INF, I have the following structure:

```
-view
--json
--jsp
---acesso
----login.jsp
---erro
----publico
----privado
---privado
----admin.jsp
----customer.jsp
--xml
```

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you know that you are getting to the handler method in your Controller.  Typically a 404 in Spring MVC means that no mapping was found.  See Spring MVC documentation for `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: when I run the application, the url displayed in the navigation bar contain the correct mapping from controller (acesso/login), but even so, a 404 error is displayed.

Comment: Per your view resolver,acceso login should be in jsp folder and jsp under view.

Comment: What kind of URLs does your app need to handle? You mapped there *.jsp. What URL are you testing with your app?

Comment: it's exactly in this way. My thought in this moment it's something is wrong with the configuration for the dispatcher servlet in the WebAppInitializer.java class, but it's just a hunt, I am not sure.

Comment: Andrei Stefan, I am testing in this moment a URL which references a JSP view, located in the folder /WEB-INF/view/jsp/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, then I solve this problem modifying the mapping string in the controllers: instead of use, by example,

```
@RequestMapping(value="login")
```

I use this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="login.htm")
```

(or other extension, depending of type of the view - jsp, json or xml). Now it's working fine.